# Displaying image from database using repeater without HttpHandler in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, database

## Is it possible to display the image?

The **CategoryName** was able to display fine,
but the **CategoryImage** displayed as array of byte

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <%#Eval("CategoryImage")%> <%#Eval("CategoryName")%>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

```
SqlDataReader dtrImage = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader();
Repeater1.DataSource = dtrImage;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

Output:

```
Animal System.Byte[]
Food   System.Byte[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only is this possbible, but I fact recommend doing this.

You can even do this for files as opposed to say the image in a database.
(the reason why is security - you OFTEN don't want files mapped to a folder that users can type in a URL to get say a PDF or whatever.

So, you read the file, and stream it out.

The nice part is any image, image button or whatever you place on the form can be sent the picture, and you don't require some silly handler or "some other" place beyond the code.

So, say we have a simple repeater like this

(kind of card view layout).

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="mybox">
            <div style="text-align: center; padding: 2px 10px 12px 10px">
                <asp:Button ID="cmdMyView" runat="server" Text="View"
                    CssClass="btn-info" Style="float: right"
                    OnClick="cmdMyView_Click"
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                <br />
                <h3><%# Eval("Fighter") %></h3>
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Width="180" Height="120" />
                <h4>Engine</h4>
                <asp:Label ID="EngineLabel2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Engine") %>' />
                <h4>Description</h4>
                <asp:Label ID="DescLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSel" runat="server" Checked="false"
                    myid='<%# Eval("id") %>' />

            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

You note the image control in above.

So, we have a image in the database.

About the only requirement is of course you need to have saved in that database not only the file (as raw byte data), but you need the file extension.

So, for above, we fill the repeater with this code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        LoadGrid();
}

void LoadGrid()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
    {
        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Fighters";
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            Repeater1.DataSource = rstData;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

So, that loads the repeater rather nice.

So, the only part left is to fill out the image.

In fact, this works even without a repeater anyway.

So, for each "repeat", we need to pull the image from the database.

So, in most cases, that means we use the row data bound event of the repeater.

thus, this:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ( (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) ||  
        (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) )
    {
        Image ctlImage = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("Image2");
        DataRowView rData = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
        byte[] MyBytes = (byte[])rData["MyImage"];
        string MineType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(rData["FileName"].ToString());

        rData["FileName"].ToString();
        ctlImage.ImageUrl =
            $@"data:{MineType};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(MyBytes)}";
    }
}
```

And the result is now this:

[image]

And note how I have a button in the repeater. the code for that "view" button, as a example code is this:

```
    protected void cmdMyView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        RepeaterItem rRow = (RepeaterItem)btn.NamingContainer;
        int MyRowIndex = rRow.ItemIndex;
        int MyPK = Convert.ToInt32(btn.CommandArgument);

        Debug.Print("Row index click = " + MyRowIndex);
        Debug.Print("Pk data base = " + MyPK);

        // get say the engine from the row click
        Label lblEngine = (Label)rRow.FindControl("EngineLabel2");
        Debug.Print("engine = " + lblEngine.Text);
```

That allows me to get the row index, the database PK, and even example code to pull one value out of that repeater.

output:

```
Row index click = 3
Pk data base = 4
engine = 1 × Pratt & Whitney F135-PW-100 afterburning turbofan
```

## Edit: Above only really great for a few SMALLER images

So, often to just display a few thumb nails etc., then I do suggest just a stream out of the image from the database as a base64 string is fine.

HOWEVER, and this is a big however:

If you doing to display more then a few images, and you want that page to have post-backs (in place of say some link button to move on in the application), then as suggested in comments?

Then, it near always BETTER to use + build a handler for this.

This is especially if the repeater and web page in question will and does need post-backs. (if it does not, then turn off viewstate for the image control).

So, a 2nd approach (and often the most common example). is thus to add a handler.

So, the handler (add->new item->Generaic handler).

So, that handler would look like this:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{

    int ImageID = 0;
    if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
        ImageID = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["id"]);
    else
        throw new ArgumentException("No parameter specified");

    SqlCommand cmd = new 
      SqlCommand($@"select FileName,MyImage FROM Fighters where id = @id");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ImageID;
    DataTable dt = General.MyRstP(cmd);

    context.Response.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(dt.Rows[0]["FileName"].ToString());
    context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dt.Rows[0]["MyImage"]);

}
```

And now the markup for the image control can look like this:

```
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Width="180" Height="120"
                 ImageUrl='<%# @"~/MyImage2.ashx?id=" + Eval("ID") %>'   />
```

So, the result is much the same, but a BIG whopper of a difference is the 2nd example will cache the image, and if you need/want/expect to have post-backs on that page, then the 2nd example is STRONG suggested if the images are anything more then a rather small type of thumbnail preview.

With the first example, the images are not cached, and if  you need post-backs, then the view state will actaully be sending the images BACK to the server when you post-back. This thus can be rather slow.

I actually recommend with the first example that one disable view state for the image control.

Note that with this 2nd example, you have to create that image handler page, but you do thus remove the on row data bound code. So, a trade off here.

So, while your post SPECIFIC asked for not creating a handler?

it is a good idea - and how important to use a handler will be based on many factors, such as how many images, how big they are, and does the resulting page require post-backs. You have to pay VERY close attention to this issue of post-backs, since if you don't, such pages can run VERY slow with a poor internet connection.

Comment: This sends back all images in base64 format (causing huge responses), bypassing any caching mechanism HTTP offers (each image will have to be loaded from database and through code for each request again), all under the veil of "security" and "silly handler". I would not recommend this approach, but use a handler indeed (if you're hellbent on still using WebForms in 2023) and apply proper security measures making sure people can't request resources to which they have no permissions to view. You also mention having to know the image format, yet hardcode JPEG.

Comment: Actually, the page size and what is sent to the browser is not any more (or less) data size wise then if you used a image handler.  At the end of the day, we don't wind up sending a raw binary image, and if your handler going to send as the same format anyway. And yes, this is a example on SO, so I hard coded the mine type.  And yes, the browser does cache the base64 images - since that's how they all quite much work. (if the browser did not cache the image, then how come those images survive post-backs without a image re-load then, hum??? (but, I will edit post for mine type).

Comment: So, code updated without hard code of mine type. But I'm still waiting how one does not have to re-bind the image on post-backs if the browser not caching the image? And in fact, using this approach means you REDUCE the number of http requests on a page! - so there are advantages, and there are pro's and con's to this approach. It is not all "one" way, or the "other" way here - there are advantages as well as disadvantages in this approach.

Comment: Of course it's more data. First, because you use base64 instead of binary, a 33% increase. Second, because the image responses can't be cached. Every request of the page containing the repeater will have to send the images to the client again. Why not on postback? Because, well, hit F12 and inspect your requests: because _the client first sends them to the server_. It's called Viewstate. Using the displayed approach has many disadvantages, and you only save the separate requests when the images aren't cached; for every successive request , you have to send way less data.

Comment: Well, you can gzip the data. So, often it not that much more, and can be "close".  So, I'll accept that you often see increased image size without gzipped. And since one will minimize post-backs, then it not much of a issue. With a handler, then in most cases you still exposing a pk id of the image to the client side - and that means they can change that id. As I stated, this is not all one way, or the other way. It also depends on how many images, and how large they are to be.  As I stated, there are pro's and con's. For smaller images such as repeater result, then this is a great approach

Comment: However, a good recommend and idea on your part? it's still a VERY good recommend. I have added a 2nd example using a handler. I suppose those with not enough experience when to use one approach or the other? They are better off using a handler for this.

Comment: Does the "Filename" stand for the file's name in database? or the DataColumn of the Image?

Comment: In my case, when I saved the raw binary image to the database, I also saved the file name in a column. So, yes, in this cases, "just" the file name (no path information) was saved. That was done to get the "mine mapping". if you "know" the file extension type, then you can replace (or even hard code) the content type with say "image/png". So, if all images are say a png, then  context.Response.ContentType = "image/png" would work.  so, you can even save JUST the file extension if you wish. But as a general rule, you need/want to set the content type. You can hard code if you know image type.

Comment: So MyImage is the raw binary image saved in database, and FileName was the name of the original file. As noted, this 2nd column is not really required, but you need/want to know the raw binary image "type" you saved. If as noted all images are say a jpeg, then context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg" could be used in place of the getMineMapping type. (that built in function (requires .net 4.5 or later) will simple return the same text for a given file extension.

Comment: If I just replace "Filename" with "MyImage" (Which is the DataColumn of the raw image), it only display the first image from database.
If I replace getMimeMapping with Context.Response.ContentType = "image/png", the whole page seems like doesn't work. (Rendered everything into image, I think)
Does that mean it only work if I add another string text column to save the image's file name?

Comment: in my code, FileName was JUST the orgiinal file name used when the raw binrary data of hte image was saved into colum MyImage. So, I have 2 columns in the database, one is just the file name, say like dog.png. I only saved the original file name for "possbile" future use. So, the ONLY real important column name I have and used was MyImage. Of course, you would in your code replace the column name of MyImage with whatever column name you have/had. As I stated, if you don't have file name saved such as dog.png, then you of course don't need to use mineMapping to get picture type..

Comment: I suppose you could hard code the file name in the get mine mapping function and use:  string MineType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping("dog.png");  The ONLY part that matters is the picture type. As I stated, you could ALSO just do this: MineTyupe = "image/png". But that assume a image of type .png. so, what was the original image type used to create the raw binary column you have in the image?  Was it.gif? Was it png? Was it jpeg? You need that information, EVEN if you did't save the file name along with the raw column. So, I can't read your mind, and I can't know what YOUR column names are.

Comment: I not all that sure that the Mr. Obvious issue here is that My code assumes and has a column in the database called "MyImage". I assume you would replace that with YOUR column name, which I assume is called "CategoryImage". so, in your repeater, you still need to drop in a image control. But YOU don't have a column name called "FileName", and you don't have a column called "MyImage". So, in my code example, you would replace "MyImage" with your column name - which I am "guessing" is called CategoryImage. And of couse since you don't have a column called FileName, then hard code the mine type

Comment: Sorry, it was just multiple same file in the database. Yes, as you stated, just hard code the MineType to the file's type and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use web method API that receives imageKey and write in response image file.
if use Asp.Net Form ,I suggest check Global.asx abilities.
If use Mvc , I suggest write a action that return FileResult

Now use url of web method api in your ui
code :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
       <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:image src=<%#Eval("ImageUrl")%>\>
       </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

another way is use base64 format for display your image that I do not suggest because it makes your page heavy.

Comment: There is no image URL or path to the picture - the picture(s) in question are stored in the database.

Comment: imageUrl means is generate a url that execute your action or method.you must write a web method api.

Comment: Ah, ok, that's fair. As suggested then, that makes sense - my bad and apologies.